# How can I access the javadoc from a .jar file in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, datepicker

I recently downloaded the microba datepicker and it comes with three JAR files: the source code, the compiled coled and one JAR for javadoc.

I use netbeans and tried everything within my limited abilities to get access to that documentation, but just couldnt make it ... can you help me please to solve that problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `tried everything within my limited abilities to get access to that documentation`? If you have a JAR file of the Javadoc you can simply unzip it.

Comment: @Perception: jar xf javadoc.jar (in the console) unzipped it .. didnt know i had to unzip it. thanks. at least i can read it in browser now!

Comment: Try adding that JAR as a library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To read the javadoc from a .jar-file one first has to unpack it. To do so, open your console, navigate to the folder where the jar file is located an unpack it using the following command:

**jar xf yourFileNameHere.jar**

Then you can access the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to unzip the zip-file to your preferred location, go  to your netbeans and on your project you search for **Libraries** and you  right click on **>>>Libraries** and select  **>>>Add JAR/Folder** located your extracted file and then click on open.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. In the Libraries folder of my project there are the microba_sources.jar and the microba_javadoc.jar, but they dont work together. I can include the classes from the _sources.jar file into my code, but i get a javadoc not found notification: [screenshot1](http://imageshack.us/a/img26/3051/58693025.jpg)  [screenshot2](http://imageshack.us/a/img201/1017/18646691.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, Right click plusztester(prototyp) project and select >> **Resolve Project Problems** select the missing files and resolve them by locating the right files.

Comment: i have netbeans 7.3, but i cant find such an option ... :-(